# Executable Jar created by Gradle bootRepackage missing jars

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

**What i'd like to do:**

Creating an executable Jar using gradle, and eclipse as IDE.
Jar should include all libs required to run, and could be used inside a docker container.

**Issues so far:**

org.springframework.boot is not included in the Jar.

**Code:**

src/main/java/SampleController.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller    
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
        String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()  
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    api 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

springBoot {
  mainClass = "SampleController"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

**Command used:**

*In workspace/project/build/libs*

java -jar project.jar

**Error:**

```
java : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
At line:1 char:1
+ java -jar RSSFeedAggregator.jar
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Exception in th...TargetException:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at SampleController.main(SampleController.java:18)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to this. Does anyone has any ideas on how to resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

guess I found the solution.

From my understanding, when running directly in eclipse, gradle api / implementation automatically add the jars at runtime.
But when creating the fat jars with :bootRepackage, runtime libs need to be explicitly added. (The program runned well on eclipse directly)

```
runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

This resolved my problem.
I won't close the topic yet if anyone has something to add on this issue.